# Android: How do you keep compatibility between specific version to latest android version

Tags: android

As a newbie I am not sure how do I make sure my app works between certain android version range. [According to latest statistics](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), it seems that 2.3.3 (gingerbread) is still heavily used out there (other than ICS and JB). But now that Kitkat has made its way, many apps are updated to support that as well while still keeping compatibility with older versions of android.

So essentially what are general guidelines to support latest version of android as well as specified minimum old version. For example, how do I make sure my app works starting from 2.3.3 (gingerbread) to latest 4.4 kitkat ?

Also can emulators be used to make sure app works in specified range?

*P.S: I know that can be specified via app manifest file but that's not my question* I am just looking for how to actually make app **compatible** between the two versions.

Thanks for your suggestions and helpful ideas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different approaches to reach that goal.

First thing: 
    Despite the min sdk you want to support you should always use the latest sdk to build your app.
At this point, choose the min sdk you want to support and declare it inside the manifest.
If you are using eclipse with lint enabled it will be very easy at this point to spot if you are using unsupported api for that platform level.
If you want to use a new api and make it only available on newer devices you have basically two approaches:

1. use reflection (discouraged)
2. use @TargetApi annotation on the methods that use new api and call
   those methods only on devices on which those api are available

   ```
   if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK)>whatlevelyouwant){
       callMethodWithNewAPI();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of information on Google's 'Support Different Versions' Site: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Generally it says that you should support 90% of the devices out there (which means you can leave out Android 2.2, but should start with 2.3).

However, some new apps don't start with 2.3 but start with 4.0. This makes life much easier in words of testing.

Answer (score 1):

In ADT you can use the ADV to generate differents emulators, one for each Android version you want to support and test.
It´s not as good as a real device but a useful starting point

Answer (score -1):

You can define [MinSdk and maxSdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) in your manifest file.. This will define which [Android Versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) will be supported by your application.

```
android:minSdkVersion
An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. 

android:maxSdkVersion
An integer designating the maximum API Level on which the application is designed to run.
```

So if you want your app to be compatible with 2.3 to the latest version you can define in your manifest file :

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

If you don't specify `maxSdkVersion`, it will take the latest released android version. So this line impllies your application is compatible with all devices having android 2.3 or above ..

Comment: I know that can be specified via app manifest file but that's not my question